# Probability gcse question

Tags: probability, statistics

> In a group of 15 people there are 5 men and 10 
>   women. 
>   one of the men and three of the women are wearing red jumpers. 
>   A man is selected at randomfrom a group. 
>   Then a women is selected at random from a group

Find the probability that the people selected are both wearing red jumpers

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p87xB.jpg

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What is "gcse"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: General Certificate of Secondary Education.  It's what happened to O-Levels in the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a bit unclear as to how the selection is made.  I'm assuming:  a person is randomly chosen from the group *and happens to be a man*, and so on.

Then the answer is $$P = \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{10}$$

Comment: Thank you I definitely over complicate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge of a probability tree diagram. you can solve this.
Its basically listing out all the possibilities and assinging proportions/probabilities to them. It is shown below.

[image]

Probability that a man is selected AND he is wearing a red jumper is $\frac{5}{15} \times \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{15}$ (Note: the probability decreased because of increased condition i.e. and red jumper)

Likewise, Probability that a woman is selected AND she is wearing a red jumper is $\frac{10}{15} \times \frac{3}{10} = \frac{1}{5}$ (Note: the probability decreased because of increased condition i.e. and red jumper)

probability of finding any (either man or women) of people wearing red jumpers is the sum of the above two cases (Note: the probability increased due to summing and because of laxed condition (can be either man or women))

so answer is $\frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{5} = \frac{4}{15}$

Comment: Sorry, I answered the question of "What is the probability of selecting a man and him wearing a red jacket OR probability of selecting a woman and her wearing a red jacket?"